# How to store the option value from dropdown menu in codeigniter?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, input

I have a dropdown menu with four options

```
$options = array(
              '0'  => 'Choose option...',
              '1'  => 'Option1',
              '2'    => 'Option2',
              '3'   => 'Option3',
              '4' => 'Option4'
            );
echo form_open('Welcome/create_user');
echo form_dropdown('dropdown_menu',  $options, '0');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Register');
```

When I use:

```
$this->input->post('dropdown_menu');
```

It gives me the index of the option (1,2,3..etc.) But how do you get the "option1","option2" etc.?

Comment: if you want the textual value posted, why use numeric ones in first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because when you are initializing drop-down codeigniter giving array index as value.

but if you want value then you can do like this:

```
$options = array(
              '0'  => 'Choose option...',
              'Option1'  => 'Option1',
              'Option2'    => 'Option2',
              'Option3'   => 'Option3',
              'Option4' => 'Option4'
            );
echo form_open('Welcome/create_user');
echo form_dropdown('dropdown_menu',  $options, '0');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Register');
```

or you have to initialize array in controller also

```
$options = array(
              '0'  => 'Choose option...',
              '1'  => 'Option1',
              '2'    => 'Option2',
              '3'   => 'Option3',
              '4' => 'Option4'
            );
$key = $this->input->post('dropdown_menu');
echo $options[$key];//use as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `$options` array accessible in wherever you're catching your post data. Then get a value by key:

```
$key = $this->input->post('dropdown_menu', TRUE);
$value = $options[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a dropdown in codeigniter is to have the data variable outside the dropdown tag. Please copy and paste the code below in to a page to get an idea how it is working and adjust to your needs.

```
            <?php echo form_open(); ?>  

                <?php $data = array(
                            'option0'       =>  'Select Option...',
                            'option1'       =>  'Option 1',
                            'option2'       =>  'Option 2',
                            'option3'       =>  'Option 3',

                ); echo form_dropdown('options',$data,'','Options') ?>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```